# Powershell script to pull device names and dates from API older than specified date

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to create a Powershell script, using the Cylance API, which:

1. Find all device older than 45 days
2. Store these devices as Name: Date into a .csv file
3. Delete all of these devices

I have a Perl background, but I am new to Powershell, and so I figure I could do it this way:

Find each device older than 45 days, store them as Name -> Date in a hashtable, print the hashtable to a .csv file, and then delete the devices stored in the hash table.

However, I am only getting a few devices, and the csv file is blank. This is what is stored in the HashTable(I know for a fact there should be WAY more devices stored in this HashTable).

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
MPB8NTVR                       2018-12-11T17:25:38.259
FENAPPTESTNICK                 2018-12-11T15:50:31.924
SERSENM2                       2018-12-11T14:57:50.109
FENWAPNMSP40                   2018-12-07T20:26:04.005
FENXENAPPD01                   2018-12-13T16:42:34.517
FENXENAPPD02                   2018-12-13T16:43:54.908
M5CG7193HR4                    2018-12-14T17:10:20.588


param (
    [string]$AccessTokenPath = "Documents\Cylance\",
    [string]$CylanceGenerator = "CylanceGeneratorTest.exe",
    [int]$PageNumber = 1,
    [int]$PageSize = 200,
    [string]$CylanceURI = "https://protectapi.cylance.com/devices/v2?page=$PageNumber&page_size=$PageSize",
    [string]$CylanceDeviceURI = "https://protectapi.cylance.com/devices/v2/",
    [string]$OutFile = "$PWD\testfile.txt",
    $TodaysDate = (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff'),
    $date = 45
)

$AccessToken = & $AccessTokenPath\$CylanceGenerator
$CSVHash = @{}

do {
    [string]$CylanceURI = "https://protectapi.cylance.com/devices/v2?page=$PageNumber&page_size=$PageSize"

    try {
        $CylanceRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $CylanceURI -Header @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $AccessToken"}
    }
    catch {
        $CylanceError = $_ 
    }

    $response = $CylanceRequest | Select-object -ExpandProperty page_items | Select-Object -Property id, name, date_first_registered, date_offline

    $response | ForEach-Object {
        try {
            $uri = $CylanceDeviceURI + $_.id
            $CylanceDeviceReq = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Header @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $AccessToken"}
            $DaysOffline = $CylanceDeviceReq.date_offline

            if ($DaysOffline) {
                "Days offline = " + $DaysOffline
                $TimeDiff = New-TimeSpan -Start $TodaysDate -End $DaysOffline
                "TimeDiff.Days = " + $TimeDiff.Days
            }

            if ($DaysOffline -and ($TimeDiff.Days -le -$date)) {
                "Adding " + $_.name + " " + $DaysOffline
                $CSVHash.Add($_.name, $DaysOffline)
            }

            $temp = $_ | ForEach-Object {
                if ($_.date_offline) {
                    New-Object psobject -Property @{
                        "Name"         = $_.name
                        "ID"           = $_.id
                        "Date Offline" = $CylanceDeviceReq.date_offline
                    }
                }
                $temp | Export-csv -Append $PWD\raw.csv -NoTypeInformation
            }

        }
        catch {
            $CylanceError = $_
        }
        $PageNumber++
    }
} while ($PageNumber -le $PageSize)

#$CompHash
$CSVHash
```

Comment: Not familiar with their API. Do they have a demo page/user we could test your code against?

Comment: can you post the sanitized contents of `$response` t o work with? if not, then i suspect you need to spend some time in the debugger looking at the actual values of things ... especially your various date-evaluation sections.

Comment: trebleCode - as for (Not familiar with their API. Do they have a demo page/user we could test your code against?)  --- none that I've was able to get to prior to my org getting on the Cylance bandwagon.

Answer (score 1):

As for …

> I have a Perl background, but I am new to Powershell

Are you saying, you've done some ramp up on PowerShell before you started down this path and that you've already leveraged the Cylance modules / scripts from the MS PowerShellGallery, GitHub and could not leveraged them directly or tweak them to your needs before trying what you've posted?

> Cylance-API-PS
>   https://github.com/Maliek/Cylance-API-PS
>
> CylanceDSCScript.ps1
>   GetNewThreatsAndDeviceLastDay.ps1
>   GetOldDevices.ps1
>   GetOldDevicesAndRemove.ps1
>   GetRansom.ps1
>   GetSubClassificationsThreats.ps1
>   GetThreatsAndDevice.ps1
>   README.md
>   SendMailLatestThreatsAndDevices.ps1
>   UploadMultipleHashes.ps1
>   hashes.txt
>
> Cylance-API-Powershell-example
>
> https://github.com/regexninja826/Cylance-API-Powershell-example
>
> https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CyCLI/0.5.6/Content/CyAPI.ps1
>
> https://github.com/jan-tee/cycli

Hash tables do not restrict the amount of data that is returned.

So, pull the raw dataset natively first to make sure you are getting the count you'd expect, that work out the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

What stands out to me as strange is the line where you assign value to $response. I'm not familiar with the object you're dealing with, but at first glance I suspect a misuse of -ExpandProperty on that line. That would return a property as a string. You then pipe to second Select-Object, also unusual. Try something like $CylanceRequest.page_items | Select-Object....

I could be mistaken, but that's the bit that jumps out at me as iffy.